# Restricting number of rows in Datalist

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net I am using  Datalist in that I want to limit row count and want the sort to be in vertical. Let me know how to do this.
Ex: I want my list to be like this

```
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

Comment: Like this ? you miss something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first issue, restricting to number of rows is, just pass the required data to datalist and for vertical , use this property `RepeatDirection="Vertical"`

Comment: RepeatDirecttion="Vertical" is giving colums as two but not effecting number of rows.